# How can I paste my password when pushing?

Tags: magit, copy-paste, passwords

Instead of memorizing all of my passwords, I use a password manager to store them for me. Currently, since I use Magit for most Git purposes, I need to go through several steps in order to push:

1. `P` `P` `RET`
2. `C-g`
3. `M-x term` `RET` `RET`
4. `git push` `RET`
5. Copy my password from my password manager
6. `C-c C-j` `C-y` `RET`

And then afterward, I seem to have a still-running process from Magit's failed push, in addition to the Term mode buffer I created, to deal with.

Is there a less laborious way to enter my password when pushing with Magit?

**Edit**: ... oh. Well, this is embarrassing. You can apparently just hit `C-y` directly when Magit asks for your password. I thought I tried that before, but apparently not.

However, it seems that passwords entered this way are not stored in Git's credential cache, so I now need to enter my password every time I push. Is this a bug?

Comment: You can usually avoid passwords by using SSH access.

Comment: @abo-abo Do you mean that I would never need to enter a password except when cloning, or that I would only need to enter a password once a day or so? Because if you mean the latter, I already have my cache set to 24 hours timeout.

Comment: "it seems that passwords entered this way are not stored in Git's credential cache[...] Is this a bug?" - Yes, it seems so. https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/2309

Comment: I mean by giving my public SSH key to the remotes I never enter a password. Ever. And it's very safe.

Comment: @abo-abo OK, I'll look into that, thanks! This Magit bug should still be fixed, though.

Comment: There are a few things cooking which will address this issue. The feature branches should be merged soon.

Comment: @tarsius Thanks again man, you're awesome. :)

Comment: Obviously, but it's @npostavs who did all the work in this case. ;-)

Comment: @tarsius You both get [virtual cookies](http://www.lameapps.com/images/eatcookie_screenshot1.png) then. :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you have noticed, you can yank the password when Magit is reading
it in the minibuffer (this works pretty much always when user input is
read in the minibuffer for whatever purpose).  So the sequence is more
like this:

1. `P` `P` `RET`
2. `C-y` `RET`

This might or might not cache the password, depending on various
settings.  First you need to tell Git to cache the password, which can
be done using:

```
git config --global credential.helper cache
```

Unfortunately, even with that setting, the entered password didn't get
cached before Magit v2.3.  The problem was that the daemon, which Git
starts to cache the password, terminates when receiving SIGHUP, and
that Emacs sends SIGHUP when git finishes.  The daemon cannot (yet) be
told not to terminate on SIGHUP, and Emacs cannot be told not to send
SIGHUP - which obviously is a bit of a problem.  Magit v2.3 works
around this by starting the `git credential-cache-daemon` directly,
before calling e.g. `git push`.

Also new in v2.3 is support for the built-in `auth-source` package.
This allows retrieving the password from any of the sources it supports
and then forwarding it to Git.  To use this, you have to customize
`magit-process-find-password-functions`.

Finally you might also want to consider using public key authentication.

Comment: @npostavs Oh, it's not "hang ub" :-)

Comment: Do you by any chance know of a good way that I can learn the why, what, and how of SSH (particularly with Git), starting from the basics? I've never used it before, and I'm having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around it.

Comment: The guides provided by Github are okay: https://help.github.com/categories/ssh/ and focused on the use-case at hand.